# AWS CDK Deployment Issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-cdk, amazon-ecr

I was trying to deploy a sample public image from ecr to cdk. So I written some code for that in a way that it does not uses a nat gateway and for that reason I created some vpc endpoints to aws services. Here is the full code for reference,

```py
from aws_cdk import (
    Stack,
    aws_ec2 as ec2,
    aws_ecr as ecr,
    aws_ecs as ecs,
    aws_ecs_patterns as ecs_patterns
)
from constructs import Construct


class Microservice(Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

        vpc = ec2.Vpc(
            self,
            "MyVpc",
            max_azs=2,
            nat_gateways=0,
        )
        vpc.add_interface_endpoint(
            "S3Endpoint", service=ec2.InterfaceVpcEndpointAwsService.S3, private_dns_enabled=False)
        vpc.add_interface_endpoint(
            "SSMEndpoint", service=ec2.InterfaceVpcEndpointAwsService.SSM)
        vpc.add_interface_endpoint(
            "EcrDockerEndpoint", service=ec2.InterfaceVpcEndpointAwsService.ECR_DOCKER)
        vpc.add_interface_endpoint(
            "EcrEndpoint", service=ec2.InterfaceVpcEndpointAwsService.ECR)

        cluster = ecs.Cluster(self, "MyCluster", vpc=vpc)

        ecs_patterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService(
            self,
            "MyFargateService",
            cluster=cluster,
            cpu=512,
            task_image_options=ecs_patterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedTaskImageOptions(
                image=ecs.ContainerImage.from_ecr_repository(
                    ecr.Repository.from_repository_name(self, "SampleRepo", "ecs-sample-image/amazon-ecs-sample"))
            ),
            memory_limit_mib=1024
        )
```

The cdk synth ran fine but when I deployed it then in aws I got an error saying:

```
STOPPED (Resourceinitializationerror: unable to pull secrets or registry auth: execution resource retrieval failed: unable to retrieve ecr registry auth: service call has been retried 3 time(s): RequestError: send request failed caused by: Post "https://api.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/": dial tcp 209.54.183.210:443: i/o timeout)
```

Anyone please help me to understand the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible issues I see here:

1. You're using public ECR and [that can not be accessed](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/1160) from an isolated subnet. You only have isolated and public subnets as you've disabled NAT gateways. If that's the case, try adding a NAT gateway, deploying the service to a public subnet, or not using public ECR.
2. The service is created before the interface endpoint. There is a missing dependency here. The service might not be able to use the interface endpoint as it's not ready  yet. Try adding a dependency (`service.node.add_dependency(endpoint)`) or separating the VPC and service into two different stacks. It's considered best practice to separate network, data and application stacks.